# Is it possible to continuously substract values from two different columns in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes; one dataframe contains orders, the other one contains items that are in stock.

```
# Sample DF 1 - Orders
# +--------------+------------+---------------+----------------+
# | T-Shirt Size | Ordered By | Shop Location | Order Quantity |
# +--------------+------------+---------------+----------------+

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(
    columns = ['size', 'ordered_by', 'shop_location', 'order_quantity'],
    data = [['L', 'Tom', 'London', 1], 
            ['M', 'Alice', 'Manchester', 1],
            ['S', 'Alice', 'Manchester', 1],
            ['S', 'Georgia', 'Newcastle', 1], 
            ['L', 'Bart', 'Manchester', 3], 
            ['M', 'Bob', 'Manchester', 1], 
            ['L', 'Toby', 'London', 2]]
)
```

```
# Sample DF 2 - Stock
# +--------------+---------------+--------+-------+
# | T-Shirt Size | Shop Location | Stock  | Price |
# +--------------+---------------+--------+-------+

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(
    columns = ['size', 'shop_location', 'stock', 'price'],
    data = [['S', 'London', '5', '7.99'],
            ['M', 'London', '9', '7.99'],
            ['L', 'London', '3', '8.99'],
            ['XL', 'London', '7', '8.99'],
            ['S', 'Manchester', '2', '7.99'],
            ['M', 'Manchester', '2', '7.99'],
            ['L', 'Manchester', '15', '8.99'],
            ['XL', 'Manchester', '8', '8.99'],
            ['S', 'Newcastle', '2', '7.99'],
            ['M', 'Newcastle', '11', '7.99'],
            ['L', 'Newcastle', '4', '8.99'],
            ['XL', 'Newcastle', '1', '8.99']]
)
```

After merging the dataframes, I would like to deduct the order amount from the amount of items that are in stock in a specific shop location in an ongoing fashion.

I'm getting as far as this:

```
df_merge = pd.merge(
    df_1,
    df_2,
    how='left',
    left_on=['shop_location', 'size'],
    right_on=['shop_location','size']
    )

df_merge['stock'] = df_merge['stock'].astype(int) - df_merge['order_quantity'].astype(int)
df_merge
```

```
  size ordered_by shop_location  order_quantity  stock price
0    L        Tom        London               1      2  8.99
1    M      Alice    Manchester               1      1  7.99
2    S      Alice    Manchester               1      1  7.99
3    S    Georgia     Newcastle               1      1  7.99
4    L       Bart    Manchester               3     12  8.99
5    M        Bob    Manchester               1      1  7.99
6    L       Toby        London               2      1  8.99
```

Obviously, this does what it is supposed to and simply deducts the value order_quantity in the order quantity column from the value in the stock column.

However, what I would like to achieve is something like this:

```
  size ordered_by shop_location  order_quantity  stock price
...
1    M      Alice    Manchester               1      1  7.99
...
5    M        Bob    Manchester               1      0  7.99
...
```

Comment: show the full output for `Manchester` location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a cumulative order quantity:

```
df_1['cum_order_quantity'] = df_1.groupby(['shop_location','size'])['order_quantity'].cumsum()

# your merge code
# ...

# deduct by cumulative order quantity
df_merge['stock'] = (df_merge['stock'] - df_merge['cum_order_quantity']).astype(int)
df_merge
```